# Как в vaadin подключить стили CSS?

Tags: vaadin

Добрый день, пытаюсь подключить данной конструкции

```
 Label label2 = new Label("This text has a lot of style");
    label2.addStyleName("mystyle");
    layout.addComponent(label2);
```

данный стиль

```
.mystyle {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

но как это сделать не могу понять, данный стиль прописывал в папке проекта mytheme в файле style.css не подключается там же создавал отдельный файл mystyle.css результат то же в чём причина ?

Comment: а этот `style.css` подключается в конечный html?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev  Да.

Comment: Надо смотреть конечный html. У `label` должен быть `class="mystyle"`

Comment: Смысл в общем в том что чтобы `.mystyle{...}` подключился к элементу надо чтобы у элемента в `html` был аттрибут `class="mystyle"`; c vaadin я совсем не знаком(

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev хорошо буду знать, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При генерации maven'ом из vaadin archityp'a генерируется такая структура:

```
src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\
addons.scss
mytheme.scss
styles.scss
```

добовлять mystyle надо в mytheme.scss